# I need some kind of software or windows 10 configuration to do temporal profiles

Tags: windows

I really need something to make "temporal" profiles in Windows 10 in a way if a guest comes to PC's,make sure he doesn't leave any kind of sensitive information (or even homeworks...) because those PC's are lent and we actually have a problem with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it with temporary profiles. Instead, clone the entire hard disk with [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) (i.e. create a full backup). Once you get the PC back, overwrite everything with the backup.

It's not only about sensitive information. Someone could also manage to install a virus using a zero day exploit. You want to get rid of all those viruses as well.

I'm using Clonezilla regularly for apprenticeships. It's not super easy to use, but once you know it, it really works well. It's free of cost for private and commercial use, which is great as well. It's available for regular BIOSes and UEFI.